# What formats can be displayed with type="application/x-shockwave-flash"

Tags: html, flash, object

I have an object as below. For the object to display in IE I added `type="application/x-shockwave-flash"`. What formats (images, videos, animations) can be displayed using `type="application/x-shockwave-flash"`?

```
<object data="smiley.gif" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="200" height="250">
<param name="src" value="smiley.gif">
<param name="autoplay" value="false">
<param name="autoStart" value="0">
</object>
```

Secondly is there a better alternative for `<object>` when displaying in IE. I need to have multiple formats because this will be used for ad displays on digital screens and clients will load different formats ads.

Comment: That `type="application/x-shockwave-flash"` only supports SWF files. The SWF app itself contains code to handle different tasks like audio, video, images, games etc etc... Maybe use I-frames for loading different formats. That means one html embeds a Flash (SWF) as ad or banner & another HTML has JPG image as ad. Then you load relevant html in the i-frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) No, there's not any alternative to using `<object>`

2) It's Adobe Flash (read about it in Wiki)

3) It's being  deprecated. Various browsers stopped or will stop support of Adobe Flash in a year or two.

4) That's why  you should prepare to switch your client ads/convert them to HTML5 (it's a next rich media format, it seems). Google Swiffy will help you with that on the server-side, Adobe Authoring tools, I believe? also can export content created with former Flash editors to HTML5